# How to set DataGridView column header through a linq query?

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq, datagridview

I have an sql database for vehicle details. I want to display some fields of the linq query on a datagridview control with different column headers with spaces  other than the database field names. I tried it as below but it gives an error. How do I do this?. Thank you guys.

```
 var vlist = from lst in dc.tblVhcleInfos
             select new {"Registration Number"= lst.RegNo, "Make and Model"=lst.makeModel, "Year of Manufacture"=lst.YOM};
             dataGridView1.DataSource = vlist;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set up Custom names for Dynamic LINQ Classes, declare class first, add DisplayName attribute to properties, like this

```
// Define new Class
public class VhcleInfo 
{
     [DisplayName("Registration Number")
     public string RegNo { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Make and Model")
     public string MakeModel {get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Year of Manufacture")
     public int Year { get; set; }
}


// Create IEnum for Defined Class
var vlist = from lst in dc.tblVhcleInfos
         select new VhcleInfo() { RegNo = lst.RegNo, MakeModel = lst.makeModel, Year = lst.YOM };
// Set Data Source
dataGridView1.DataSource = vlist;
```